# Mapping hibernate application in offline mode not working

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am new to the hibernate framework.when i am running hibernate sample example code it is working fine if internet connection is available.If internet connection is not available then it is not working and is giving error like below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hb.example.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at com.hb.example.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:17)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 3 more
```

So can any help for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced and solved the similar problem.

Reason of the problem: 
You might be having old version of Jar files, hence your IDE say eclipse must be using some online JAR files supplied by some third party typically JBoss. The problem is common when you have hibernate plugin installed in your IDE.

Solution:
Download the latest libraries from hibernate's website. go here 
http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

Add all the Jar files in your project. Remove older version of Jar files.
Clean and rebuild your project.
Disconnect the internet.
This should work. :)